# Почему не срабатывает header location?

Tags: php

Код регистрации пользователей. После нажатия на кнопку , редирект не происходит

```
 <?php
 if (isset($_POST['reg'])) {
  $login = htmlspecialchars($_POST['login']);
  $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST ['password']);
  $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST ['email']);
  $bad = false;
  session_start();
  unset($_SESSION['error_login']);
  unset($_SESSION['error_password']);
  unset($_SESSION['reg_success']);
  if ((strlen($login) < 3) || (strlen($login) > 32)) {
  $_SESSION['error_login'] = 1;
  $bad = true;
  }
  if ((strlen($password) < 6) || (strlen($password) > 32)) {
  $_SESSION['error_password'] = 1;
  $bad = true;
  }
  if (!$bad) {
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "Hunter");
  $password = md5($password);
  $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO users ('login', 'password', 'email') VALUES 
  ('$login', '$password', '$email')");
  $mysqli->close();
  $_SESSION['reg_success'] = 1;
  header("Location: index.php");
  }
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: а что в ответ приходит?

Comment: @AlexanderZonov не надо. вы может еще и перед обычным выводом статус 200 отправляете?

Comment: Да, действительно не хватало / перед Index.php. У меня встречный вопрос. У меня стоит условие на пароль и логин, если логин меньше 3 символов - ошибку должно выдать. Собсна она и выдаётся, НО. если хоть одно поле ведено не правильно, то меня почему то кидает по пути этого файла(что выше указан)

Answer (score -3):

Может заголовки отправлены до того как вы пытайтесь сделать `Redirect` ?
Найдите в файле `php.ini` строку поставьте на `on` (по умолчанию поставлен `off`).Так вы можете узнать проблему.

Или просто вместо редиректа с помощью пхп используйте js:

```
echo '<script>
    location.href = "/index.php";
</script>'
```